# How do I get Gson to serialize a list of basic name value pairs?

Tags: android, json, serialization, gson, key-value

I'm trying to serialize a list of BasicNameValuePairs using type adapters and Gson

```
ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> kvp=new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
kvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("car","ferrari"));
kvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("speed","fast"));
```

this is the result I want

```
{"car":"ferrari","speed":"fast"}
```

instead of this

```
[{"name":"car","value":"ferrari"},{"name":"speed","value":"fast"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To serialize this according to specification you need to make a custom type adapter that will handle the generic list. First create the class that will do the proper formatting on the output.

```
public class KeyValuePairSerializer extends TypeAdapter<List<BasicNameValuePair>> {
@Override
public void write(JsonWriter out, List<BasicNameValuePair> data) throws IOException {
    out.beginObject();
    for(int i=0; i<data.size();i++){
        out.name(data.get(i).getName());
        out.value(data.get(i).getValue());
    }
    out.endObject();
}
/*I only need Serialization*/
@Override
public List<BasicNameValuePair> read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    return null;
}
}
```

Then use a custom Gson builder to use that type adapter to create the proper JSON string.

```
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder= new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(KeyValuePairSerializer.class, new KeyValuePairSerializer());
    Gson gson=gsonBuilder.create();
    Logger.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),gson.toJson(kvp, KeyValuePairSerializer.class));
```

Comment: How should the deserialization function look like?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/ This works for defined JSON objects. For anonymous you need to do something like https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types.

Comment: Note: The first argument to registerTypeAdapter should be the class being serialized, not the Serializer.