# Android - JSON - How to create JSON that has X objects and an array inside each one of them

Tags: android, arrays, json

I need to produce a JSON with many objects inside, and each of them to have an array of strings. I'm using Java, more specifically Android.

I want to produce something like the following:

```
"manager1": [
        {"product1":"xxxx"},
        {"product2":"yyyy"},
        {"product3":"zzzz"}
    ],
"manager2": [
        {"product1":"xxxx"},
        {"product2":"yyyy"},
        {"product3":"zzzz"}
    ]
```

I have a Bean class which has this manager and array of products information, am just having trouble to see how that would fit inside my AsyncTask class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not appending numbers to your keys. That just messes up your java classes.

Use lists for everything.

```
{ 
    "managers": [
        {
            "name": "manager1",
            "products": ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz"]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "manager2",
            "products": ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz"]
        }
    ]
}
```

You POJOs / beans would look like so

```
class Foo {
    List<Manager> managers;
}

class Manager {
    String name;
    List<String> products;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, very elucidative

Comment: @Guilherme Please mark the answer as "Accepted" if it has solved your issue.

Comment: @Mangesh Done. Could you help me with one more thing? I'm not sure how I'll pass all these Lists through my AsyncTask to become String... params

Comment: @Guigs You only need to pass one `Foo` object or one `JSONObject` class. `new WebTask().execute(obj);`... Or, instead you can use Volley or Retrofit, which are easier to mess with than AsyncTask once you learn them

Answer (score 0):

If you have objects you can use Gson library to convert object into json string.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

If you ask about structure of classes in your Java code it will be the Map of the android.util.Pair arrays.

```
Map<String, Pair<String, String>[]> map;
```

But.... you have to create your own serializer and deserializer for Pair class. The answer you can find here: [How do I get Gson to serialize a list of basic name value pairs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521816/how-do-i-get-gson-to-serialize-a-list-of-basic-name-value-pairs)